# How to tell if a property in a sub-object exists?

Tags: javascript

I have a object defined as

```
{
    "query" :
    {
        /* snip */
    },
    "aggs":
    {
        "times" :
        {
            "date_histogram" :
            {
                "field" : "@timestamp",
                "interval" : "15m",
                "format" : "HH:mm",
                "min_doc_count" : 0
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How can I tell whether `interval` in `aggs.times.date_histogram` exists, so that I can manipulate it?

Clarification: I can not be sure that any of the parent objects to `interval` exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the value is always a non-blank string, just test it for truthiness:

```
if (aggs.times.date_histogram.interval) {
    // Use it
}
```

You might cache the result of those property lookups. Though it's unlikely to really matter for performance, it may be useful for code maintainability:

```
var interval = aggs.times.date_histogram.interval;
if (interval) {
    // Use it
}
```

If you need to worry that each level may not exist, it gets more verbose:

```
if (aggs &&
    aggs.times &&
    aggs.times.date_histogram &&
    aggs.times.date_histogram.interval) {
    // Use it
}
```

There's [a question with several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key) about writing a function for that.

Comment: You guessed the nature of my inexact question, I do need to worry about each level. I'll update my question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @pjcard: No worries. You said in another comment you were surprised there wasn't a shorter way. A few years ago on the es5-discuss mailing list there was talk of a short-circuiting property accessor operator which would let you do that. I forget what the operator was, but say it was `..`, then you'd do: `aggs..times..date_histogram..interval` and you'd get `undefined`, rather than an error, if any level didn't exist. IIRC, it didn't meet the "pulls its syntactic weight" requirement and wasn't advanced. :-| Too bad, in my view, but...

Answer (score 3):

You can check it with `typeof`:

```
if(typeof aggs.times.date_histogram['interval'] !== 'undefined') {
    // ... exists ...
}
```

Another method is using the `in` keyword (this one is prettier and more obvious imho)

```
if('interval' in aggs.times.date_histogram) {
    // ... exists ...
}
```

The above is assuming `aggs.times.date_histogram` exists (and doesn't need an existence check)

---

**Update**: For checking the existence of everything leading to the value you need, you can use this:

```
function getProp(_path, _parent) {
   _path.split('.').forEach(function(_x) {
       _parent = (!_parent || typeof _parent !== 'object' || !(_x in _parent)) ? undefined : _parent[_x];
   });
   return _parent;
}
```

You can call it like:

```
getProp('aggs.times.date_histogram.interval', parent_of_aggs);
```

Will return the value of `interval` if it is defined, else it will return `undefined`

Comment: In case you need to check recursively you can look at this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key

Comment: @Treesrule14 Yours was the answer I am looking for - I'm surprised that from that answer there's no good way to do it. I'll update my question to make it clear that the intervening objects may be absent.

Comment: I used getProp in the end, very handy. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's not working for me - it seems to return an empty object in the case that it is not defined.

Comment: Oh, i see. Perhaps its something to do with what you are passing as the second argument. Been using `getProp()` for a couple years without any issues so far. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/11xrrxo1/

Answer (score 0):

```
test = {
"query" :
{
    /* snip */
},
"aggs":
{
    "times" :
    {
        "date_histogram" :
        {
            "field" : "@timestamp",
            "interval" : "15m",
            "format" : "HH:mm",
            "min_doc_count" : 0
        }
    }
}
};
```

Use this:

```
if(test.aggs.times.date_histogram.interval) {
    alert('true'); //your code here
} else {
    alert('false'); //your code here
}
```

Comment: This will usually work but has the same caveat as T.J. in that the value must be assumed to always be "truthy". If the value of 'interval' was "falsey" (ex: false) for some reason, it would behave as if there was no property defined.

Comment: You are right, i assumed the type from the example code. techfoobar's answer is more correct.